# cannot use external JNI function in two different classes, unsatisfied link error

Tags: android, linker, java-native-interface, android-ndk

For an Android application, I have implemented an external function in C, which I would like to use in two separate classes.

In the first class (my main Activity UI), I call the appropriate loadLibrary:

```
System.loadLibrary(...);
```

In the same class, I define the function as native:

```
public native int dissectPacket(byte[] header, byte[] data, int encap);
```

After doing this, I can call the native function with *no problem* in the first class.  I do not get any unsatisfied link error.

Now, I want to use this function in another class.  I figure I do not need to load the library again.  In the second class, at the bottom, I also define:

```
public native int dissectPacket(byte[] header, byte[] data, int encap);
```

However, when I try to use the native function in the second class, I get:

```
07-22 23:13:13.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6737): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dissectPacket
```

What is the proper way to use the function in both classes?  If I do not redefine the function as native in the second class (called *Packet*), I get the error:

```
The method dissectPacket(byte[], byte[], int) is undefined for the type Packet
```

BTW, I do NOT want to use: class1.dissectPacket(...);  I am trying to avoid passing the class.

Comment: It would help if you showed us the corresponding methods on the native side of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined actually two separate functions. One for the first class and another one for the second. They will need two separate JNI stubs. You, probably, only have stub and implementation for the first one.

JNI and Java, in general, always refer to methods of the specific class.

Comment: does the System.loadLibrary() have to occur in the class that will use the native function?

Comment: No, it can be loaded anywhere prior to first use.

Comment: I get it now.  I forgot that when you declare the native function, you specify the class also.  Therefore, the stub really does belong to the class.  I created one for both classes now.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

"BTW, I do NOT want to use: class1.dissectPacket(...); I am trying to avoid passing the class."

If you want to do that, the member functions need to be static, otherwise the class is implicitly passed as a parameter (I don't know how because I've never done it, static functions have always worked for me, but it has to happen to work properly).

So change your method stubs to:

```
public static native int dissectPacket(byte[] header, byte[] data, int encap);
```